# Spivak Proof: $\left| \frac{1}{x} \right| = \frac{1}{|x|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

..... if $x \neq 0$

Spivak's Proof:

> $\left| \frac{1}{x} \right| \cdot \left| x \right| = \left| \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot x \right | = 1$ so $\left| \frac{1}{x} \right| =  \frac{1}{\left|x\right|}  $

I am fine until the 'so'. Is the 'so'? $$ 1 \cdot \left| {x}^{-1} \right| = \frac{1}{\left| x \right|}$$

This strategy seems to be used a lot by Spivak.

Comment: So long as $a,b \not=0$ you have $a \cdot b =1 \iff b= \frac{1}{a} \iff a= \frac{1}{b}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this

$$\left| \frac{1}{x} \right| \cdot \left| x \right| = \left| \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot x \right | = 1$$

we have shown that $\left| \frac{1}{x} \right|$ and $\left| x \right|$ are one the inverse of the other, that is $\left| \frac{1}{x} \right| =  \frac{1}{\left|x\right|}$.

---

**Edit**

As an alternative

- for $x>0 \implies \left| \frac{1}{x} \right| = \frac1 x =\frac{1}{\left|x\right|}$
- for $x<0 \implies \left| \frac{1}{x} \right| =- \frac1 x =\frac{1}{\left|x\right|}$

and for $x=0$ they are both not defined, therefore they are equivalent.

Comment: Nice…. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $|\frac{1}{x}| \cdot |x| = 1$ then $|\frac{1}{x}| = |x|^{-1}$. This follows by the axioms on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Of course!!!! thank you.